# How can I correct my code to format my result a little differently?

Tags: python, formatting

In the following Python code (where the function should be able to take in random info and return the name and average time of the person with the highest average):

```
def the_fastest(times):
    fastest_person = []
    quickest_time = float('inf')

    for person_data in times:
        person_name = person_data[0]
        person_times = person_data[1:]
        total_time = sum(person_times)
        avg_time = total_time / len(person_times)
        if avg_time < quickest_time:
            quickest_time = avg_time
            fastest_person = [person_name]
        elif avg_time == quickest_time:
            fastest_person.append(person_name)
    
    return fastest_person, round(quickest_time, 2)

#example times for testing
times = [['Jason', 11, 11, 11.2, 10.9], ['Wally', 11, 11.5], ['Sheri', 12, 25], ['Jimmy', 10.1, 10.8, 12.1], ['Tina', 10.15, 10.223, 10.185, 10.22], ['Carmen', 12.15, 12.2, 12.18, 12.33]]

print(the_fastest(times))
```

My result is returning the correct information, but in the wrong format. I'm getting back: `(['Tina'], 10.19)`

but I'd like it to be in the format:
`['Tina', 10.19]`.

I've tried the brute force method of telling it to `print(f"['{name}',{time}]")`, which works, but I'd like something a little more elegant.

Comment: What should the result be if more than one person has the fastest time?

Comment: You might want something like `return [*fastest_person, round(quickest_time, 2)]`?  Note that if you have multiple people that means you'll have multiple people in the list, but using the `*` operator means that you'll get a single list instead of a tuple where the first item is a list.  But if you only want a single name, you probably don't want `fastest_person` to be a list in the first place (and you could do this all very neatly with the `max()` function).

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the edge case of multiple people having the same fastest time, so I'll ignore it. You might want to consider how to handle it per suggestions in the comments.

```py
def the_fastest(times):
    # fastest_person = []  # <-- fastest_person isn't a list, it's just one person
    fastest_person = None
    quickest_time = float('inf')

    for person_data in times:
        person_name = person_data[0]
        person_times = person_data[1:]
        total_time = sum(person_times)
        avg_time = total_time / len(person_times)
        if avg_time < quickest_time:
            quickest_time = avg_time
            # fastest_person = [person_name]  # <-- again, don't use a list for one person
            fastest_person = person_name
        elif avg_time == quickest_time:
            fastest_person.append(person_name)
    
    # return fastest_person, round(quickest_time, 2)  # <-- this is where you create your return list
    return [fastest_person, round(quickest_time, 2)]

#example times for testing
times = [['Jason', 11, 11, 11.2, 10.9], ['Wally', 11, 11.5], ['Sheri', 12, 25], ['Jimmy', 10.1, 10.8, 12.1], ['Tina', 10.15, 10.223, 10.185, 10.22], ['Carmen', 12.15, 12.2, 12.18, 12.33]]

print(the_fastest(times))
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I'm new to coding so I've just been using what I've been taught to try to Frankenstein things together. This is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the elements of the list `fastest_person` (even if there are multiple people tied for fastest), you can use the `*` operator to spread the elements of that list into another list, rather than nesting them:

```
    return [*fastest_person, round(quickest_time, 2)]
```

But if you want to only get a single name for each time, you probably don't want put the maximum names in a list in the first place. Here's an example of how to do this with a very small amount of code using the built-in `max` function (with a little help from the built-in `operator` and `statistics` modules):

```
from operator import itemgetter
from statistics import mean

def the_fastest(all_person_times):
    name, mean_time = max((
            [name, mean(times)]
            for name, *times in all_person_times
        ), key=itemgetter(1)  # get the max time from [name, time]
    )
    return [name, round(mean_time, 2)]

times = [['Jason', 11, 11, 11.2, 10.9], ['Wally', 11, 11.5], ['Sheri', 12, 25], ['Jimmy', 10.1, 10.8, 12.1], ['Tina', 10.15, 10.223, 10.185, 10.22], ['Carmen', 12.15, 12.2, 12.18, 12.33]]

print(the_fastest(times))  # ['Sheri', 18.5]
```